# Omitting types inside a model

Tags: logic, model-theory

I conjecture that following statement is **false**, but I cannot construct a counterexample

> Let $N$ be an $L$-structure, with $L$ countable.
> Let $p(x)\subseteq L$ be a type that is not isolated
> i.e., there is no $\varphi(x)\in L$ such that $N\models\forall x\ [\varphi(x)\rightarrow p(x)]$.
> Then there is an $M\preceq N$ such that $M\not\models\exists x\ p(x)$.

The statement is true if we require $N$ to be $\omega$-saturated (essentially, by the omitting types theorem).

Comment: I think my answer to the linked duplicate answers your question. To be precise, the structure $M_a$ defined there has no proper substructure, and in particular no elementary substructure omitting the non-isolated type $\eta_a$.

Comment: Of course! Thank you.